# Get date-time in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to get date and time using javascript in a web view, but it returns `baseUrl`  instead of date/time. Code:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlstring, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Code to get date/time :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var d=new Date().getTime();
console.log("Get Date :: ",d);

</script>
```

Output in LogCat :

```
Get Date :: blank 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, you'll need to enable JavaScript with:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: We'd probably have to see more about what you're doing. For instance, what is the full value of htmlString? Also, why are you using the version of loadData() that uses a base URL if you're passing in an empty string. I've seen that version used with a null value, but not an empty string.

Comment: Thanks scott for reply now my problem is resloved i got date from webview using javascript handler